# Why is it possible to pass current to another insulated human while touching a plasma tube?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, plasma-physics, insulators

I work in a museum and we have a large plasma tube (I do not know any details of the current used within the tube). When I place my hand on the tube and then hold out my finger and touch another human being (who's not touching the tube) we can pass a current at times large enough to make a small spark. Both of us are insulated from the ground with rubber shoes.

How is this possible?

Does it have anything to do with the fact that even though we are somewhat insulated we are not completely insulated and current can dissipate into the air around us and thus we are at a relatively close to a grounding potential compared to potential on the outer surface of the plasma tube?

Comment: Where does that spark appear? Could it be possible that your plasma tube is some Tesla transformator which generates a really fast AC field.

Comment: The spark appears between the two fingers almost touching. I don't know whether a DC or an AC current is being used. Would an AC current still allow an arc to form between the electrodes?

Comment: I think the tube has a net charge on its surface and when you touch it you gain some of the charge (it's okay for charges to accumulate on insulators, as they generally do on the outer boundaries).  If you accumulate a lot of the charge, then when near another person you can cause a static discharge.  This is just like rubbing your feet on the floor then touching someone and shocking them.

Comment: I assumed that too but it would reach a limit eventually, if we hold fingers we can feel the current continuing to flow which means it must be getting grounded

Comment: @Fiztban - If you shut off the plasma tube while touching it, you will stop seeing the static discharge.  While it is on, it is continually charging up the outer wall of the insulator because it is constantly exposed to an electric field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plasma tube works on the same principle as plasma bowl, then there must be Tesla transformer which generates high voltage at high frequency. The high voltage (like 10kV to 1MV) would be enough to travel through your body. However there is also so called [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) which ensures that high frequency current is conducted in a thin layer on the surface of your skin and not through muscles and internal organs.

The fact that you wear shoes is irrelevant first because the floor itself is not conductive and second because you care about the current between you and the other person not you and ground.

As for the dissipation it is kinda like that. The Tesla transformer creates high frequency alternating current which moves electrons in the gas towards it and back so that you see sparks but you don't get electricaly charged when you touch it. You can read about it on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil#Air_discharges

You don't even need plasma tube to pass spark to another person try rubbing your rubber shoes on the carpet. You will genenerate static electrical charge which you can then pas to another person. It's a little different principle but it is similar.

Comment: A quick check online shows that plasma tubes are surrounded by a thick insulator.  How are you then transferring electric current to the person touching the plasma tube?  The correct answer is static charge forming on the outer wall of the plasma tube, not making people act as conducting wires.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had forgotten to consider that you can pass a current from being statically charged. So what is causing the sparks between me and someone else is the alternating current involved in making the plasma lightening making a potential that alternates in direction so to speak?

Comment: @honeste_vivere ah so what you are saying is that as you put your hand in the insulating tube of the plasma tube the charge drawn to my hand attracts charge on the outer surface that then discharges through me and the other human?

Comment: @Fiztban - Yes, it is not a current flowing from inside the tube.  It is a charge accumulation on the outside wall of the insulator.  Remember, conductors can redistribute charges homogeneously throughout their volume but insulators can only really have charges accumulate on their surfaces (well, there are complications and caveats, but this is accurate enough for this discussion).

Comment: Don't worry I understand the implied caveats but I guess I was needing someone to point my reasoning in the right direction; I had assumed if current was passing through the glass would be a very big issue with safety. Thank you for your help in reasoning the logic, please feel free to write up an answer that I can accept.

Comment: @Fiztban It does **not** have to do with static charge accumulation on the outside of the container. The frequency is high enough to couple capacitively through the glass wall. The glass separating the plasma and your hand acts like a capacitor, which acts like a conductor at high enough frequency.

Comment: @polwel - Yes, the conductivity is frequency-dependent but glass does not become a conductor at frequencies relevant to this question.  If you Google the following "SiO2 electrical conductivity vs frequency" and click on the images you can find all sorts of plots showing this.  For instance, one shows that silica changes from $10^{-8}$ S/m at ~20 Hz to $10^{-3}$ S/m at ~3 MHz.  The conductivity of germanium, a semi-conductor, is three orders of magnitude higher.  Unless the plasma tube is operating well above the THz range, I doubt the tube is a conductor in the strict sense.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I was not talking about the conductance in this sense. I meant that two electrodes (here: plasma and OP's hand) form a capacitor. This capacitor conducts current at high frequency (the complex impedance is given by $Z=\frac{1}{\omega C}$). The dielectric properties of glass (compared to air) will enhance $C$ and thus also the currrent flow. For instance, with $C=1\,\mathrm{pF}$, $\omega=100/s$ , one finds $Z=10\,\mathrm{M\Omega}$. Surely that is low enough to carry a substantial current at high voltages.

Answer (score 0):

> When I place my hand on the tube and then hold out my finger and touch another human being (who's not touching the tube) we can pass a current at times large enough to make a small spark. Both of us are insulated from the ground with rubber shoes.  How is this possible?

The most likely explanation is an [electrostatic discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge), not a net current flowing from inside the plasma tube.  If a current were flowing, you would have health and safety issues and plasma tubes would probably not be for public entertainment.  [Insulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_(electricity)) can accumulate electric charge on their outer surfaces but charges cannot freely flow throughout their volume like [conductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductor).

I am guessing when you shut the tube off for the day and come back the next morning that it has accumulated slightly more dust than other surfaces near by.  Unless you discharge the excess charge on the surface of the [glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass), it will remain for relatively long times.  You might even be able to "feel" the static fields (you actually feel this because of the response of small hairs on your skin) when it is off and no one has touched it.

> Does it have anything to do with the fact that even though we are somewhat insulated we are not completely insulated and current can dissipate into the air around us and thus we are at a relatively close to a grounding potential compared to potential on the outer surface of the plasma tube?

No, I do not think there is a net current flowing from within the tube.  The most likely cause is a static discharge similar to what occurs if your rub your feet on a carpet and then touch someone.  During the static discharge, yes current flows through the arc but you are not conducting a current from the ground into the next person and back into the ground.  During the rubbing of your feet on the carpet, you are creating electric charges that do work to redistribute themselves evenly over your body.  Since neither your outer skin or the carpet are good conductors, the charge remains (i.e., it does not flow back to the carpet just by standing still... well it does slowly dissipates but it is very slow).

> Can glass at high frequencies behave like a conductor?

The short answer is yes, if the frequency is high enough.

The long answer is that for most purposes, glass (i.e., SiO<sub>2</sub>) is a really good insulator.  It was used for years for high voltage power lines and other purposes because of its high resistivity, but tends to attract condensation and had other issues so the utilities switched to ceramics.

To illustrate that glass is a good insulator across a broad range of frequencies, I Googled the phrase *SiO2 electrical conductivity vs frequency*.  I found the image below, which is taken from *Hassan et al.* [2015].

[image: silica conductivity vs. frequency]

It shows that the [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) of silica (i.e., SiO<sub>2</sub>) has a conductivity that ranges from ~10<sup>-8</sup> S/m at ~20 Hz to ~10<sup>-3</sup> S/m at ~3 MHz.  For comparison, [germanium](http://chemistry.about.com/od/moleculescompounds/a/Table-Of-Electrical-Resistivity-And-Conductivity.htm) has a conductivity of ~2.17 S/m or roughly three orders of magnitude higher than glass at ~3 MHz.  Germanium is considered a semi-conductor and is used in [transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) and [diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode).  For comparison, good conductors have conductivities above ~10<sup>7</sup> S/m like silver and copper.

Thus, unless the plasma tube power supplies are opperating above the THz range, I do not think the glass is acting like a conductor.  A quick Google search shows that plasma tubes typically operate in the ~few MHz range, not above THz.

## **References**

- Hassan, S.A., H.M. Gobara, M.M. Gomaa, R.S. Mohamed, and F.H. Khalil "Can microwave assisted in situ reduction of supported Pt nanoparticles challenge the chemical method in controlling the dispersion profile-catalytic performance relationship?" *RSC Adv.* **5**, pp. 54460--54470, doi:10.1039/C5RA08116E, 2015.

## **Update**

In an answer to another [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/354193/59023) CRDrost shared a link to a Princeton Plasma Physics Lab paper on plasma globes, which can be found at http://w3.pppl.gov/~szweben/Papers/coauthorpapers/Plasma%20Ball_POP_final.pdf.  In there they state:

> The current is capacitively coupled through the inner glass bulb to the plasma filaments, and from the outside glass sphere back to the power supply in the base.  The current inside the plasma ball is presumably carried by the visible filaments.  The filament structure inside the ball can be changed by touching the outer glass sphere with a grounded wire or a finger, which produces a single bright filament.  The current through such a filament was measured by an external AC Pearson meter to be ~1 mA.

It appears that the surrounding air is acting like a ground and when you place your finger on the glass, your finger is a much better ground than the air.  Each filament is actually a superposition of thousands of filaments flashing at upwards of 25 kHz and the total current is rather small at ~1 mA.

From these observations it does appear that each filament carries a net current, and when an individual touches the glass, the glass sphere acts as a dielectric to capacitively couple the finger and the inner source.  Thus, it appears that *polwel* was correct.  When a finger is not on the glass tube, the electrons flow back-and-forth between the inner source and the glass tube/wall.  Not all electrons will make it back and the outer glass enclosure can charge up, similar to rubbing a balloon on hair.  Thus, my original post was not inaccurate.