# Plasma globe - circular fringes

Tags: electromagnetism, interference, plasma-physics, geodesics

why there are dark bright fringes (multiple of them very similar to newton rings) around each arc path where arc is connected to the inner electrode?

I know [why electrons form these paths](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354019/) but I can't explain to myself why there are regions with a dark spots on inner electrode (yet alone stable symmetrical rings!)

i can confirm i observed at least 4 rings, stable enough to be counted by naked eye, although i couldn't capture a photo myself but i appended a picture which is very similar to what I'm describing.

[image: arc connected to inner electrode of a plasma globe]